# How to make a login system in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, system

I am trying to make a simple login system in javascript. 
The code should be for multiple users

e.g: user: love pass: cat, user2: mom pass2: love etc.

I need the code to redirect users to certain pages
e.g. if username textbox has the text LOVE and pass is cat then user should be redirected to page1.html
if username is MOM and pass is love then user should be redirected to page2.html

P.S. I know all security issues that occur when using javascript login but those are for a school project.

I tried:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function Getstats()
{
window.status=('Attempting to Login to user area.')

var AccId;
var iName;
AccId = document.iAccInput.iAccID.value
iName = document.iAccInput.iName.value

if (AccId == "" || iName == "")
{
alert('\nERROR\nYou must enter ALL Details,\nto View your statistics.\n');
window.status=('Missing data or Invalid. Check spelling and Ensure Names are in Correct Case.')
}
else
{

var location=(iName + ".html");
this.location.href = location;
window.status=(' Verifying: ' + iName +' Please wait........');
}
}

</SCRIPT>
<hr><FORM NAME="iAccInput">
<CENTER>
<TABLE BORDER="1px" bordercolor="#c0c0c0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">
            <p><FONT SIZE="3" FACE="Arial"><B>User Name:</B></FONT>
              </p></td>

        <TD>
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="iName" MAXLENGTH="15">
        </td>
        <TD> &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <TD ALIGN="RIGHT">

            <p><FONT SIZE="3" FACE="Arial"><B>Password:</B></FONT>
              </p></TD>
        <td>
            <INPUT NAME="iAccID" MAXLENGTH="15" HEIGHT="50">
        </TD>
        <td align="center">
            <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" Login " onClick="Getstats()" HEIGHT="40" WIDTH="50"><BR><br>
            <INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE=" Reset " onClick="window.status=('RESET: Please enter your USERNAME and ACCOUNT ID.')" WIDTH="50">

        </td>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

But this use another kind of algorithm.
If anyone know, please let me know. thanks you!

Comment: Don't do this, people only have to view the page source code to see what the password should be.

Comment: that's really bad approach,  anyhow what share what problem you are facing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, I know everything you want to say about me, but let me answer his question

you have to put this

```
var location = '';
if (iName=='love' && AccId=='cat') {
    location=("page1.html");
}
else if (iName=='mom' && AccId=='love') {
    location=("page2.html");
}
else alert('Wrong pair');

this.location.href = location;
```

inside your `else` statement to make it work, BUT DON'T DO LIKE THAT

[DEMO](https://www.google.ru/search?q=obfuscate+javascript)

of course, you can verify it on server sending XMLHttpRequest or using POST and PHP or other server-side languge, but here I can suggest to use encryption 1.add this to your head section:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha1.js"></script>
```

and replace password verifing with:

```
if (iName=='love' && CryptoJS.SHA1(AccId)=='9d989e8d27dc9e0ec3389fc855f142c3d40f0c50')
```

and

```
else if (iName=='mom' && CryptoJS.SHA1(AccId)=='9f2feb0f1ef425b292f2f94bc8482494df430413')
```

[DEMO WITH ENCRYPTION](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/22TQy/1/)

next step is 2. to [obfuscate](https://www.google.ru/search?q=obfuscate+javascript) your code. Your code could look like this

```
var _0x51a3=["\x73\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73","\x41\x74\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x4C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x75\x73\x65\x72\x20\x61\x72\x65\x61\x2E","\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65","\x69\x41\x63\x63\x49\x44","\x69\x41\x63\x63\x49\x6E\x70\x75\x74","\x69\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","","\x0A\x45\x52\x52\x4F\x52\x0A\x59\x6F\x75\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x20\x41\x4C\x4C\x20\x44\x65\x74\x61\x69\x6C\x73\x2C\x0A\x74\x6F\x20\x56\x69\x65\x77\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x72\x20\x73\x74\x61\x74\x69\x73\x74\x69\x63\x73\x2E\x0A","\x4D\x69\x73\x73\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x64\x61\x74\x61\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x2E\x20\x43\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x20\x73\x70\x65\x6C\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x61\x6E\x64\x20\x45\x6E\x73\x75\x72\x65\x20\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x73\x20\x61\x72\x65\x20\x69\x6E\x20\x43\x6F\x72\x72\x65\x63\x74\x20\x43\x61\x73\x65\x2E","\x6C\x6F\x76\x65","\x39\x64\x39\x38\x39\x65\x38\x64\x32\x37\x64\x63\x39\x65\x30\x65\x63\x33\x33\x38\x39\x66\x63\x38\x35\x35\x66\x31\x34\x32\x63\x33\x64\x34\x30\x66\x30\x63\x35\x30","\x70\x61\x67\x65\x31\x2E\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x6D\x6F\x6D","\x39\x66\x32\x66\x65\x62\x30\x66\x31\x65\x66\x34\x32\x35\x62\x32\x39\x32\x66\x32\x66\x39\x34\x62\x63\x38\x34\x38\x32\x34\x39\x34\x64\x66\x34\x33\x30\x34\x31\x33","\x70\x61\x67\x65\x32\x2E\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x57\x72\x6F\x6E\x67\x20\x70\x61\x69\x72","\x20\x56\x65\x72\x69\x66\x79\x69\x6E\x67\x3A\x20","\x20\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x77\x61\x69\x74\x2E\x2E\x2E\x2E\x2E\x2E\x2E\x2E"];function Getstats(){window[_0x51a3[0]]=(_0x51a3[1]);var _0xfcfax2;var _0xfcfax3;_0xfcfax2=document[_0x51a3[4]][_0x51a3[3]][_0x51a3[2]];_0xfcfax3=document[_0x51a3[4]][_0x51a3[5]][_0x51a3[2]];if(_0xfcfax2==_0x51a3[6]||_0xfcfax3==_0x51a3[6]){alert(_0x51a3[7]);window[_0x51a3[0]]=(_0x51a3[8]);} else {var _0xfcfax4=_0x51a3[6];if(_0xfcfax3==_0x51a3[9]&&CryptoJS.SHA1(_0xfcfax2)==_0x51a3[10]){_0xfcfax4=(_0x51a3[11]);alert(_0xfcfax4);} else {if(_0xfcfax3==_0x51a3[12]&&CryptoJS.SHA1(_0xfcfax2)==_0x51a3[13]){_0xfcfax4=(_0x51a3[14]);alert(_0xfcfax4);} else {alert(_0x51a3[15]);} ;} ;window[_0x51a3[0]]=(_0x51a3[16]+_0xfcfax3+_0x51a3[17]);} ;} ;
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/22TQy/2/)

Comment: @LeonteGeorge you cannot hide it on client side, but you can encrypt and obfuscate it - nearly impossible to understand what's going on page (look through my updated post)

Answer (score 6):

You should NEVER, EVER do the username/password check in the client side, since anyone could just view the source of your javascript file and find the password pattern or even just bypass it easily. you will ALWAYS want to send the username/password to the server and have the server redirect it for you

Comment: That is actually the worst idea I've ever heard.

Comment: @LeonteGeorge since you don't have a server, you can either do a big switch statement check or you can have bunch objects containing username + password + url and loop through them

Comment: @LeonteGeorge then in database, make a table with 4 columns : ID, username, password, url and send those information to the server from javascript, have the server verify with the db and send a redirect to the url or send back the url and have the javascript to do the redirect.

Comment: @LeonteGeorge you should read about html Form, jquery ajax, basic sql, API call/REST. You would need all of them to do things the right way

Comment: Depending on the set up, doing most of the login on the client side could be done reasonably securely. It just makes no sense from a software design perspective. You have to go knee deep into all kinds of nonsense, like syncing and browser issues.

Answer (score 1):

Altough it is not advised to make a login system with javascript, it can be done reasonably securely(so the user can't see the passwords directly), you could make like a javascript loader which loads in a bunch of variables from one javascript file, then uses it in the main javascript file and uses encrypted cookies to store the loggedin variables and stuff using essentials.js(A javascript library which makes everything simpler including sessions and cookiestorage) and at last clearing the loader again, then it clears the whole javascript of the page / the javascript connection leaving no trace behind of the password file link.

This can be done in serveral ways, the esiest and probably the most secure one is something like this.

```
<div id='loader'></div>

<div id='scripts'>
<script>

document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = "<script src='passwords.js'></script>";

if(passwordinput == user1pass) {
  // This runs when the password and username match up with the variables in the loaded script
}
else if(passwordinput == user2pass) {
  //Etc..
}
else {
  console.log("User does not exist");
}

document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("scripts").innerHTML = "";
</script>
</div>
```

You could even store the passwords in the document itself, that is probably even more secure but more difficult to register new people. I have not tested if this works but I think it will. Also I advise you to only let the passwords.js file reveal itself when a key is given as a get parameter, this is really easy to do and I think you can figure that one out on your own. Also I advise you to hash the passwords to add a thin layer of protection on top of it, this is also really easy to do and I think you'll be able to figure that out by yourself aswell.

I hope this answer helped some of you visitors of this question with the same question.